# How to check all child tags of a particular parent tags count?

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

this is a sample xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<random>
  <chkr id="1">
    <ab>10.100.101.18</ab>
    <xy>5060</xy>
    <tt>pop</tt>
    <qq>pop</qq>
  </chkr>
  <chkr id="2">
    <ab>tarek</ab>
    <tt>tarek</tt>
    <ab>ffff</ab>
    <foo>pop</foo>
  </chkr>
  <chkr id="3">
    <ab>adf</ab>
    <foo>adf</foo>
    <tt>fadsf</tt>
    <ab>fadsf</ab>
    <tt>036</tt>
    <foo>.3</foo>
    <ssd>wolk</ssd>
  </chkr>
</random>
```

I want to search for tags other than the tags `<ab>` and `<tt>` in each of the parent tags `<chkr>` and get the name of the tags that appear in that parent node more than once. i.e. in the above sample xml, the output should be `<chkr id="3">` contains the tag `<foo>` multiple times.

How can I do this using LINQ-TO-XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grouping by the name of all descendants is a very easy solution:
(`x` is the name of your XDocument)

```
foreach (var e in x.Descendants("chkr"))
{
    foreach (var v in e.Descendants()
                       .Where(ee => ee.Name != "ab" && ee.Name != "tt")
                       .GroupBy(ee => ee.Name)
                       .Select(ee => new { Name = ee.Key, Count = ee.Count() }))
    {
        if (v.Count > 1)
            Console.WriteLine($"<chkr id={e.Attribute("id").Value}> contains the tag <{v.Name}> {v.Count} times.");
    }
}
```

With your XML this code would output

> `<chkr id=3>` contains the tag `<foo>` 2 times.

EDIT: If you want the results as specified in you comment, just change your code to the following:

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();
List<int> counts = new List<int>();

foreach (var e in x.Descendants("chkr"))
{
    names = new List<string>();
    counts = new List<int>();

    foreach (var v in e.Descendants().Where(ee => ee.Name != "ab" && ee.Name != "tt").GroupBy(ee => ee.Name).Select(ee => new { Name = ee.Key, Count = ee.Count() }))
    {
        if (v.Count > 1)
        {
            names.Add(v.Name.ToString());
            counts.Add(v.Count);
        }
    }

    if (names.Any())
        Console.WriteLine($"<chkr id={e.Attribute("id").Value}> contains the tag/tags {String.Join(",", names)} {String.Join(",", counts)} times.");
}
```